# Use images as labels in CNN with Caffe

Tags: neural-network, protocol-buffers, caffe, label

I am developing a CNN to do segmentation of biomedical images.

As an input I have 572x572x3 images and my labels are the images with the ground truth.

This is my data layers :

```
layer {top: 'image'  name: 'loadMydata_image'    type: 'HDF5Data'  hdf5_data_param { source: '/home/alexandra/Documents/my-u-net/my_data.txt' batch_size: 1} include: { phase: TRAIN }}

layer {top: 'anno'  name: 'loadMydata_anno'    type: "HDF5Data"  hdf5_data_param { source: '/home/alexandra/Documents/my-u-net/my_data.txt' batch_size: 1} include: { phase: TRAIN }}
```

The problem is, at the end my output is smaller than the label image and the Euclidean loss layer can not work.
Here are my last layers:

```
layer { name: 'label_reshape' type: 'Reshape' bottom: 'anno' top: 'anno_reshaped' reshape_param { shape : {dim:0 dim:-1 dim:0 dim:0}  }}

layer { bottom: 'score' bottom: 'anno_reshaped'  top: 'loss'  name: 'loss_tune'   type: "EuclideanLoss" include: { phase: TRAIN }}
```

I have this error:

```
F0722 10:43:42.478071 10809 euclidean_loss_layer.cpp:12] Check failed: bottom[0]->count(1) == bottom[1]->count(1) (980000 vs. 981552) Inputs must have the same dimension.
```

I tried to use a reshape layer but I cannot get the exact same size ..

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2):

Most probably the size mismatch is due to the convolutional layers. If you don't set padding in the convolutional layers then the borders are lost.

For example, a 32x32 input to a 3x3 kernel will give a 30x30 output.

To solve this, you can either use padding in all your convolutional layers or crop your label images to match the size of the output.

Alternatively, if you size mismatch is because you've used some pooling layers (which reduce the image spatially) and haven't upscaled in the later layers, then you need to resize the label images to match the size in the output.

Note: Reshape layer does not resize the image. It is used to "reshape" the data. The total amount of values remains the same after a reshape layer.